# truncate long text in jsf dropdownlist h:selectOneMenu

Tags: javascript, jsf

is there a quick way to truncate long texts displayed in h:selectOneMenu without having to code it from scratsh.
what i'd like to acheive is truncating long text , and add a tooltip to display the whole text.

thanks

Comment: I think you should check for jQuery for doing this trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a utility function which will be used for truncation of long text. Example:

```
function shortText(String data,int length){
     return data.subString(0,length);
}
```

Now, instead of showing the value directly, pass the value and the length to this function, and use the return value on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

For truncating longer text there are many simpler ways in css like

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

OR

```
text-overflow: hidden;
```

And the'title' attribute adds a tooltip to selectOneMenu